SwiftUI/UIKit: Overlapping gestures from parent and child
I'm trying to create a view which will represent a book. I found this Pages package on Github which integrates UIPageViewController from UIKit and allows for a .pageCurl animation which I really like. Each page is an image that covers full screen size of a device. I also have the so called "double" pages which are basically 2 separate images that form 1 context so it is very important that I can scroll from first part of the double page to second part and this is where I'm stuck. My idea was to put those 2 Images inside of a TabView() but I cant go back or forward from that double page because of the way TabView bounce works.
I setup this short example to showcase the problem. This is how I'm trying to make a difference between single and double pages with Text as example. As you can see my Page1 is a single page and when I swipe forward I get to my first double page which is TabView consisting of 2 pages and here is where I'm stuck. Now I can only scroll from Page2 to Page3 and vice versa but I can't go back to Page1 or forward to Page4 with my .pageCurl transition. I also uploaded the screen record of this short example to further clarify what I meant LINK. What I'm trying to achieve is .pageCurl transition from Page1 to Page2, then scroll from Page2 to Page3 and then .pageCurl transition from Page3 to Page4. Same should happen if we go backwards. Any ideas on how to solve this?
Pages(currentPage: $index, transitionStyle: .pageCurl, bounce: false, hasControl: false) {
                Text("Page1")
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.width, height: UIScreen.height)
                    .background(.white)

                TabView(selection: $childIndex) {
                    Text("Page2")
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.width, height: UIScreen.height)
                        .background(.white)
                        .tag(0)

                    Text("Page3")
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.width, height: UIScreen.height)
                        .background(.white)
                        .tag(1)
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())

                Text("Page4")
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.width, height: UIScreen.height)
                


You probably need to write some custom gesture handling for this one and adjust the mentioned package to support this. Also a custom TabView which uses your gesture recognition. If this is always from even page number to odd page number you could check that in your gesture handling.
